# Facebook API to search friend's properties

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-fbml

It's possible to access friend names in the Graph API.  However, I want a method - either via the graph or App API to be able to search based on specific properties.

Eg: searching for all friends from London, UK.

Or searching all friends who enjoy photography.

Any places or API that may be able to assist with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search several of the properties querying the [user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) with [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/).  For example, here is a query for all female frinds:

```
select uid, name, sex 
from user 
where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
and sex="female"
```

The location is a complex object and I am not sure if it can be queried on like the other fields.